# sql: how to use count for a particular column ,(or) to count a particular column by its field name

Tags: sql

in my query i need a to count a particular column by its field name,

```
SELECT 
  C.INC_COUNT, MIN_X, MIN_Y, MAX_X, MAX_Y, B.STATE_ABBR,
  B.STATE_NAME, B.LATITUDE, B.LONGITUDE, A.STATE, GEO_ID, 
  concat(A.LSAD_TRANS,' ' , A.NAME) DIST_NAME, 
  A.LSAD, GeometryType(SHAPE) GEO_TYPE, AsText(SHAPE) GEOM  
from SHAPE_LAYERS A 
join SHAPE_LAYER_STATE_DESC B 
  on ( A.state = B.state) 
left outer join INC_DIST_SUMMARY_ALL C 
  on (C.SHAPE_GEO_ID = A. GEO_ID)
```

here i have to count by

```
 B.STATE_NAME ,C.INC_COUNT
```

if exmple the field name `nevada` means i have to get all `neveda value count` and the C.INC_COUNT.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  SELECT count(C.INC_COUNT), MIN_X, MIN_Y, MAX_X, MAX_Y,
  B.STATE_ABBR, count(B.STATE_NAME),B.LATITUDE,B.LONGITUDE,
  A.STATE, GEO_ID, concat(A.LSAD_TRANS,' ' , A.NAME) DIST_NAME,
  A.LSAD, GeometryType(SHAPE) GEO_TYPE, AsText(SHAPE) GEOM  
  from SHAPE_LAYERS A join SHAPE_LAYER_STATE_DESC B
  on ( A.state = B.state) 
  left outer join INC_DIST_SUMMARY_ALL C
  on (C.SHAPE_GEO_ID = A. GEO_ID)
```